# Are there any alternatives to ClearDB?

Tags: mysql, cloud

I am currently running an application on heroku. I was wondering, whether there is any other cloud-enabled MySQL service out there besides ClearDB.

Best Regards

Comment: Would have loved an answer to this question...  guess it's not an official coding question.  If you found alternatives, please message me back with your discoveries.

Comment: I would have liked an answer to this question too.

Comment: I would like an answer also

Comment: Whoever closed the question assumed this is a debate question, which is not. The reason why this question exists and many other people would like an answer to (including myself) it's because the lack of options you see in Heroku for MySQL. My guess is that: No, there isn't any other than ClearDB which is pretty crappy. It's better to stick to PostgreSQL if you are using Heroku. Would love to see an alternative someday